# INDIRECT and OFFSET in the function body make a name special

Tags: excel, lambda, excel-formula, excel-lambda

I would like to write a user-defined function `CHOOSERANGE` that returns a range from 4 coordinates. The first version is as follows:

```
CHOOSERANGE = LAMBDA(row_min, col_min, row_max, col_max,
    INDIRECT(ADDRESS(row_min, col_min)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(row_max, col_max)) 
),
```

When I use it in the worksheet, I realize that the icon in front of the function name `CHOOSERANGE` is different from normal functions.

[image]

Additionally, unlike normal functions, there is no intellisense for `CHOOSERANGE`.

I realize that it is because there is `INDIRECT` in the function body. Similarly for `OFFSET`, if there is `OFFSET` in a function body, that user-defined function has odd behaviour as well.

Does anyone know if it is possible to define a function that chooses a range and doesn't have this odd behavior?

Comment: The different appearance is because CHOOSERANGE is a name created in Name Manager (all defined names register like that) - to provide some help for your function, you can populate the 'Comment' field when you choose the 'Edit Name' option from within Name Manager

Comment: A lambda function `try = LAMBDA(x, x+1)` created in Name Manager does have `fx` as icon.

Comment: @SoftTimur could you confirm once whether you are in Beta Channel or not? Since I do get `fx` icon when using `CHOOSERANGE` wish i could show you.

Comment: @SoftTimur please refer [here](https://imgur.com/gallery/WacdOfq)

Comment: Great, i just updated my Excel, and now it's fixed. Thank you. I will delete the question soon.

Comment: Share it as an answer if you want... Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, it worked for me, since I am in **O365 Insiders Beta Channel Version**

[image: CHOOSERANGE]

*`fx`* icon shows when the **Beta Channel** is enabled.

• Formula is

```
CHOOSERANGE = 
LAMBDA(row_min,col_min,row_max,col_max,
INDIRECT(ADDRESS(row_min, col_min)):
INDIRECT(ADDRESS(row_max, col_max)))
```

[image]

---

**How to enable the Beta Channel**

Click `File` --> Click `Account` --> Click `Office Insider` --> `Enable Beta Channel`

[image]